# weird bug Intellij 2020.1 - ambiguous method call Bug

Tags: intellij-idea

I searched the internet and did not find anyone has the same problem with me.

My project suddenly has a lot of errors in intellij.

The error is all like

```
Ambiguous method call. Both
getAlgorithmExecution() in ExecutionContext and
getAlgorithmExecution() in ExecutionContext match
```

They are all like

```
Ambiguous method call. Both
A and
A match
```

It's totally weird.

My project can run successfully, can be built by gradle successfully. Just show a lot of such errors in intellij.

Here is a screenshot
[image]

Comment: I downgrade to intellij 2019.3 and problem solved. It is disgusting.

Comment: Do you face the same issue with 2020.1.2 (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2020.1+latest+builds)? If yes, please file a bug report at the YouTrack (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/) providing the code sample where the issue is reproduced. Thanks